# Unclear why this ID question was deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The ID question [A Sci-Fi Movie about an orb which gives people powers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81364/a-sci-fi-movie-about-an-orb-which-gives-people-powers) was deleted by a mod just shy of a month after it was asked.  It wasn't a high-quality ID question, but it had a non-negative score and I correctly answered it.  At the most, imho, it should have been closed and down voted.

So, why was this deleted?

Answer (score 4):

It was closed without improvement for more than 9 days (or 29 days, to be precise) and thus deleted in a cleanup effort.

If you want it closed and downvoted (and even expressed thus with a corresponding close-vote), I'd rather ask you why you would want this question be left in existence.

Comment: is there a meta discussing this policy?  I know I have a dog in this fight, but it still feels wrong to be deleting questions with upvoted answers (even some that were verbally accepted as the correct answer)

Comment: @DForck42 For what, cleaning up closed questions that won't get improved? I don't know if that's written explicitly on meta off the top of my head.

Comment: no, for deleting answers that were upvoted that someone (me, for example) put at least some effort into in order to answer that question.  the question might not be of high quality, and I agree it should be closed, but if there's a positively upvoted answer it shouldn't be deleted, at least imho.  we lose those answers that future searchers could find

Comment: @DForck42 Answers don't count, though, it's the question we're talking about. Either the question is appropriate or it's not. If you really think the answer makes the question appropriate (which is rather uncommon, though), you should have reopen-voted the question (or not close-voted it). If you think the question has merit for future visitors, you should have reopen-voted the question (or not close-voted it). The answers don't exist without the question.

Comment: I 100% disagree that answer's don't count.  answers, at the end of the day, are what make stack exchange sites work.  questions are merely a way to get to the answers, aka the truly meaningful part of any se site.  if an se site was all questions and no answers, it would be utterly useless to anyone.  that's why I think deleting questions that have positively upvoted answers to them, even after they've been closed, is wrong.

Comment: even SE's standard policy agrees with this, they don't delete questions that have positively upvoted answers, because someone has taken the effort to show that the answer, despite the quality of the question, has merit on the site.

Comment: @DForck42 But then you say that the question defenitely *does* have merit for the site and shouldn't be closed. But saying a question has no merit and is of no use to the site and its visitors but at the same time the answers should be conserved *somehow* just doesn't work. You *can't* answer a closed question either. Either the question has merit or it doesn't.

Comment: @DForck42 The SE policy only applies to the automatic task, since it's automatic and they have checks in place so it doesn't accidentally delete potentially useful content. That's why the question was removed in a *manual* maintenance effort.